# Make logo smaller - Photoshop

Tags: image, svg, vector, vectorization, adobe-illustrator

I had a logo made by a freelancer. At first the logo looked great and I was very happy. But now I started to use the logo in different sizes the problems started.
The freelancer that I used doesn't answer anymore.

**Problem **

Logo on iMac, with Retina screen, looks not that bad

[image]

But in Chrome and on Windows it look really bad.

[image]

What can I do to make it look better?
This is the original design.

[image]

Comment: What tool are you using that makes this horrible mess? Try using macOS's built-in `sips` tool to resize it... `sips -z 234 480 logo.png --out small-logo.png`

Comment: Was done with photoshop!

Comment: Can you post the original logo image? Is it an svg, jpg, or transparent png? The one you posted looks like it cropped off the top of the circle and has a grey background.

Comment: @MattMcManis see edit for original. It posted both jpg as png

Comment: There are no problems with the png. It might be the website system youre using is compressing the logo and not applying anti-aliasing. On your site can you right click on the small logo and view image or go to its source link? Is it still jagged and pixelated? Like this screenshot. https://i.imgur.com/yTAg6v2.jpg

Comment: Also what website system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I've converted your png to an svg with Illustrator.

http://svgur.com/i/17o.svg

It should scale without pixelating or aliasing. Though I don't know if your website system can upload it as a logo.

It can be added to html like an image, make sure to specify the size.

https://jsfiddle.net/b1mhm5g6/

```
<img src="http://svgur.com/i/17o.svg" width="200">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple website!

http://pngtosvg.com/

- Upload your pic!
- Select 3 colors!
- Download the output file and use it for any business purposes for free!